# Need to put the image and text on same line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[This is how it's looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFTTx.png)

i need to make the icon and the text on the same line and close to each other, i tried using`display: inline-block;` but it didn't work, here's my code.

HTML:

```
<div className="Comment_Icon">
            <img src={StudentIcon} alt="StudentIcon" class="Student_Icon"></img>
            <div className="Comments">5 Class Comments</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Student_Icon {
      height: 1vw;
      width: 1vw;
    
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .IconText {
          padding-top: 0.8vw;
          font-size: 1.5vw;
        }
    
    .Comments {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

Comment: Using `vw` units for everything, including `font-size` is extremely unreliable. Where is `.Comment_Icon` defined?

Comment: The simplest soultion will be to make your Block Element div.Comments to an inline-block element. `.Comments { display: inline-block; ..}`

Answer (score 1):

Use flex in this case as shown below

```css
.IconText {
  padding-top: 0.8vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.Comments {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Comment_Icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.Student_Icon {
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Comment_Icon">
  <img src={StudentIcon} alt="StudentIcon" class="Student_Icon"></img>
  <div class="Comments">5 Class Comments</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with flexbox styling. Note that I am changing your React structure a bit and also adding a fake image. And did you mean to use 1vw? that means 1% of the viewport width and is pretty small - esp on small screens.

Using and referencing REM units is more reliable ( REM is set in the root element and is usually 16px but can be changed. But the advantage of using rems is that it is a common size that all elements can access.

```css
.Comment_Icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Student_Icon {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
}


.Comments {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Comment_Icon">
  <img src="https://hipsiti.com/uploads/default-profile.png" alt="StudentIcon" class="Student_Icon"/>
  <span class="Comments">5 Class Comments</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Student_Icon {
      float: left;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .IconText {
          padding-top: 0.8vw;
          font-size: 1.5vw;
        }
    
    .Comments {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<div className="Comment_Icon">
    <img src=https://via.placeholder.com/20 class="Student_Icon"></img>
    <div className="Comments">5 Class Comments</div>
</div>
```

I made use of `float: left;`
So the icon/image comes left and the text next to it.